# Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'. in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

hello programmers i'm writing a TSQL in-line table function, actually im not good enough in sql, when i finished my code i've got this error "Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'." , anyone know the solution please give it to me.
by the way when i clicked double-click over the error msg it's selected the last "end"

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckLogin]
(   
    @un varchar(max),
    @pw varchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
begin
    declare @unexist int, @unpwmatch int, @uid bigint
    declare @uisactivated bit , @uisdeleted bit
    -----
    set @unexist = (select COUNT(UserAccessInfo.UserId) FROM UsersAccessInfo 
    WHERE UserAccessInfo.UserName = @un OR UserAccessInfo.UserEmail = @un)
    ------
    set @unpwmatch = (select count(usersaccessinfo.userid) from usersaccesinfo
    WHERE (usersaccessinfo.UserName = @un) AND (usersaccessinfo.UserPassword = @pw) OR
    (usersaccessinfo.UserEmail = @un) AND (usersaccessinfo.UserPassword = @pw))
    ------
    set @uid =(select usersaccessinfo.userid from usersaccessinfo where
    serAccessInfo.UserName = @un OR UserAccessInfo.UserEmail = @un)
    ------
    if @uid <> Null
    begin
        set @uisactivated =(select usersaccessinfo.userisactivated from usersaccessinfo
        where usersaccessinfo.userid=@uid)
    end
    ------
    if @uid <> null
    begin
        set @uisactivated =(select usersaccessinfo.userisactivated from usersaccessinfo
        where usersaccessinfo.userid=@uid)
    end
    ------
    if @unexist = 0
    begin
        select dbo.getreportbyid('1004')
    end;
    else if @unpwmatch = 0
    begin
        select dbo.getreportbyid('1005')
    end;
    else if @uid<>0
    begin
        if @uisactivated =0
        begin
            select dbo.getreportbyid('1002')
        end;
        else if @uisdeleted = 1
        begin
            select dbo.getreportbyid('1003')
        end;
    end;
    else
    begin
        select ('successful') as report
    end;
    return
end;
```

Comment: A little indentation would go a long way here...

Comment: What does the output of getReportById look like?  You should define a table variable with the same format as that function returns, then populate it with the results you're after.

Comment: getreportbyid it's return just one column

Answer (score 8):

The problem is these lines:

```
...
RETURNS TABLE
AS
...
```

This is not valid syntax for any of the four types of user-defined functions.

Assuming that you are trying to define a multi-statement table-valued function, it should look like this:

```
...
RETURNS @YourTableName TABLE( <column-definitions>... )
AS
...
```

And then your function statements should be putting the function return data into that table before it executes the `RETURN` statement, which it also is not doing.

Comment: I think `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT ...` is valid for an inline UDF.  I'm curious what the 4th type of UDF is?  I know scalar, inline and multi-statement.

Comment: but i used on function that returns a table with returns table!

Comment: @Andomar: yes, but the posted function has a multi-statement function body that never returns anything, rather than the single-line SELECT query required by iTVF's.  And the fourth type of user-defined function is a CLR function (which can also be either scalar of table-valued).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are mixing the syntax of multi-statement table valued functions and inline table valued functions. For examples of each and some performance considerations check out my post here: http://sqlity.net/en/498/t-sql-tuesday-24-prox-n-funx/

In short, if you want to use multiple statements within a table valued function you have to declare a table variable after the RETURNS keyword and insert the rows you want to return in there in the function body. However, this type of function has serious performance implications and you should try hard to stay away from it.

Besides of that, you seem to have mismatching BEGINs and ENDs. As Barry said, "A little indentation would go a long way here" in helping you and others understand you code better.

Comment: i've got , and thank you , but there is any solution for my problem , i wanna use all this queries in one function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have ; before the if command end. Also null checing is wrong. For ex;

```
if @uid <> null -- (1) note: should be if @uid is not null
Begin
    -- query
End;     --(2)-Note: this is wrong 
Else 
Begin
    --Query
End
```

Comment: i did what u said, but i still have the same error :) thank you

Comment: @MohamadShatnawi remove all ';' which are not necessary. Also you should return a `TABLE` as the last thing of the function.